# Find and Return an object from an array of array of objects using a property value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of array of objects. Is there an ES6 way to find and return an object based on a property value?

```
const tempArray = [];
tempArray.push([{ name: 'apple', y: 1}, { name: 'orange', y: 2}]);
tempArray.push([{ name: 'pear', y: 3}]);
```

Given the value property name of 'apple', I want the object `{ name: 'apple', y: 1}` returned.

I've tried `tempArray.filter(k => k.some(e => e.name === 'apple'))` but it returns an array of array of objects which I don't want.

Thanks for your help in advance,

Comment: You do have an array of array of objects. Why not maintain a single level array in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten the array, then use `.find` to find the matching object:

```js
const tempArray = [];
tempArray.push([{ name: 'apple', y: 1}, { name: 'orange', y: 2}]);
tempArray.push([{ name: 'pear', y: 3}]);

const obj = tempArray.flat().find(({ name }) => name === 'apple');
console.log(obj);
```